# How can I in the simplest way test an XML file using JUnit testing?

Tags: xml, unit-testing, testing, junit

I need to know how I can test part of an XML file with JUnit testing. To put things into context here is the code I need to test:

```
<creature name="dwarf">
    <type class="dwarf" subclass="dwarf" tileid="dwarf.png:1"/>
    <description>You see a dwarf who works in the mine to find some iron for us.</description>
    <attributes>
      <atk value="168"/>
      <def value="26"/>
      <hp value="140"/>
      <speed value="0.3"/>
      <size value="1,1"/>
    </attributes>

<creature name="elder dwarf">
    <type class="dwarf" subclass="elder_dwarf" tileid="dwarf.png:2"/>
    <description>You see an elder dwarf, a mighty warrior tired of fighting.</description>
    <attributes>
      <atk value="214"/>
      <def value="33"/>
      <hp value="180"/>
      <speed value="1.0"/>
      <size value="1,1"/>
    </attributes>
```

I need to test if the dwarf speed is greater than the elder dwarf speed. Although, I have never tested an XML file before and only Java files so I have no clue!

Comment: I rolled back your edit as we would much rather the code was in the question, not an image of the code.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I could not see it when posted thats the reason why I added an image.

Comment: That's okay - I formatted it for you too - you just need to indent it by four spaces to make it recognised as code.

Comment: Just to let you know that the XML in this question is not properly formatted. Each tag must have a closing tag. In this case - there needs to be a closing "creature" tag after each creature definition. 
It may be useful to wrap the creature definitions by a "creatures" (plural) tag.

Comment: What is that you want to achieve in a broader context? Who created the XML? Is that also your solution? If so: you could test the logic that creates the model from some input in that program using unit tests. So if you have one module that is responsible for creating the "creatures" and their configuration you write some whitebox tests for that program. Then if that program outputs this data actual XML you can also create a test that triggers that component, then reads up the XML file to see if the data was what supposed to be. I don't see the point in just "testing XML".